# Is it possible to have a ChatGPT bot that can answer questions about sensitive information without using external servers?

Tags: chat-bots, chatgpt, ai-security

We have a lot of internal documentation that contains sensitive information.

Is it possible to have a ChatGPT bot that can answer questions about this information, to my used by users with clearance for this information, without posting the information to external servers?

I can find documentation on `embeddings`, but these seem to require posting info to OpenAI for it to be processed and stored there.

Answer (score 4):

Yes it is possible. This is a popular use-case these days. check out [privateGPT](https://github.com/imartinez/privateGPT).

Answer (score 0):

You can run open source models locally without sharing your data to any server. Nowadays to perform well you need to use GPUs for efficient running of te queries, either locally or on private clouds. You may prefer services that provide private instances of large models such as GPT / Claude (available on Azure / AWS) or use smaller models with e.g. RAG to optimize the results for your domain and data.